# How to detect deleted remote database during synchronization

Tags: pouchdb

In the case of a local database synchronized with a remote CouchDB database, during a live replication, if the remote database is deleted, how can we be aware of it?

It does not trigger ***error*** event, nor any other. We can see the 404 errors in the console however.

It may not be as possible to make the difference between a deleted database or a network error, but at least if an error is thrown it is then possible to determine which situation it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you should be able to trap that error using pouchdb.authentication.js. Something like this:

```
        authdb.getUser(name, function (err, response) {
          if (!err) {// do sync
```

[You can find the pouchdb.authentication.js API here](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Or check if the db exist before calling sync.

With those checks it would seem to be an edge case you'd ever run into that problem.

Comment: As an example : 1) you have a one-db-per-user model, the user has a local db sync to its remote db 2) the user is deleted
3) It could be useful then to know that the user is deleted so you can use this info locally and act accordingly